# Unable to open Eclipse from Dash Home

Tags: command-line, unity-dash, eclipse

I can't open Eclipse from Dash Home although it shows its icon. Eclipse was properly installed using `apt-get`.

When I launch Eclipse from Dash Home it doesn't open. It opens only through Terminal. How can I open it from the dash?

Comment: Most likely, you have an outdated .desktop file in `~/.local.share/application`. To remove: run `rm  ~/.local/share/applications/*eclipse*`, log out and back in. Should be fixed then. If it is fixed, I'll post it as an asnwer :).

Comment: Can you post  `/usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop` file ? Might not be exact name of the file, but something along those lines

Comment: @JacobVlijm post that as answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The cause

If you install an application via `apt-get`, you can be pretty sure a correct `.desktop` file is installed in `/usr/share/applications`. That leaves us the only option that there must be an outdated `.desktop` file, representing `Eclipse`, in `~/.local/share/applications`, most likely of a previous locally installed version, or some application must have created a local version of the previous `.desktop` file.

Since local `.desktop` files overrule the global ones, you will have to remove it.

#### What to do

Run the command:

```
rm ~/.local/share/applications/*eclipse*
```

This will remove all local version(s) of the `.desktop` file. Subsequently log out and back in. It should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a MENU editor to alter the launch command:

MENU editor:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caldas-lopes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ezame
```

Comment: If an application is installed by `apt-get`, very unlikely the command is wrong. almost certainly, there is a local version of the file, overruling the global one.