# eclipse.desktop on launcher being replaced on reboot

Tags: eclipse, .desktop

I've finally gotten eclipse installed on my 14.04 machine so that it launches from a new terminal with an eclipse.desktop file. I can drag it onto the launcher and when I click it everything works!

Except when I close eclipse later, shut down, boot back up, and the eclipse.desktop file is no longer on the launcher. Instead is an icon from a previous installation of eclipse that leads nowhere.

So there are two issues here, how to get rid of the icon from the previous installation, and how to get the .desktop file to stay on the launcher.

Comment: update: imgur album:[link](http://imgur.com/a/w1Prb)

Comment: Hi Tha, slightly different symptoms, same cause, same solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/767573/unable-to-open-eclipse-from-dash-home/767644#767644

Comment: Ah, I see you agree, could you mark your own question as a dupe?

Comment: yup. didn't see that one, so I'll mark mine as  a dupe. thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys. It seems that I've solved it. It seems when I uninstalled eclipse I either did it wrong (this was a while ago so I dont remember) or there was a bug when it uninstalled, and there was another eclipse.desktop file left over.

I did a grep on the .local/share/applications (what the top answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170468/how-can-i-remove-icon-of-uninstalled-application-from-application-lens-in-dash) said (but replaced "cardapio" with "eclipse")) and found there was quite a bit going on in there. turns out that's where it was. Once I got rid of it the one I made stayed.